# Redirect percent encoded URL in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

Suppose I have the following URL:

`http://example.com/%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%85-rss-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D9%87%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%B4%D8%AF/`

How can I redirect this to `http://www.example.com`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use mod_alias `RedirectMatch`, for example:

```
RedirectMatch ^/سیستم-rss-سایت-بهینه-شد/$ http://www.example.com/
```

Note that the URL-path matched by `RedirectMatch` is %-decoded.

However, if you are already using mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) for other redirects then you should use mod_rewrite instead to avoid potential conflicts. For example, in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^سیستم-rss-سایت-بهینه-شد/$ http://www.example.com/ [R,L]
```

The URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` pattern is also %-decoded. But does not start with a slash in per-directory `.htaccess` files.

Note that these are both temporary (302) redirects. To make them permanent (301) you need to explicitly include the status. ie. `RedirectMatch 301` and `R=301` respectively.

---

#### Match the %-encoded URL-path

If you did specifically want to match against the %-encoded URL (as seen in the request) then you can match against `THE_REQUEST` server variable using mod_rewrite, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%85-rss-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D9%87%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%B4%D8%AF/
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/ [R,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` server variable is not %-decoded before being passed to mod_rewrite.

However, this is now dependent on the requested URL being encoded exactly as stated. It is also marginally less efficient since *every* request will be processed by the `RewriteRule` and passed to the preceding condition.