# Encoded 301 redirects don't work, only english one does

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I have a .htaccess file that in its end I created some 301 redirects. For example:

```
Redirect 301 /site-building-from-home /
Redirect 301 /%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D /
```

For some reason all redirects with an English alias (say, s`ite-building-from-home`) works but all these with encoded aliases (Hebrew-to-machine-language) don't.

Do we have an Apache-directives/PCRE expert that can explain this phenomena ?

(Note: I used / instead a domain-name+TLD for flexibility considerations).

Comment: Related: [Redirect percent encoded URL in .htaccess](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88367/redirect-percent-encoded-url-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it states in the [Apache docs for a mod-alias `Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect):

> The old URL-path is a case-sensitive (**%-decoded**) path ...

So, assuming `/%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D` is the actual request as sent from the client, then you will need to match against the literal, percent-decoded (aka URL-decoded), text in the `Redirect` directive. From your example this would be:

```
Redirect /מזין-תכנים /
```

(Make sure your `.htaccess` file is UTF-8 encoded.)

If you want to match the percent-encoded URL, as sent from the client, then you will need to use mod_rewrite and match against `THE_REQUEST` server variable (which is *not* percent-decoded). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

You will need to enable the rewrite engine earlier in your code if not already ie. `RewriteEngine On`.

However, if you change to using mod_rewrite *redirects* then it is strongly recommended to change your mod_alias `Redirects` to use mod_rewrite as well in order to avoid unexpected conflicts.

Comment: Instead of moving all ~ 150 redirects to mod-rewrite oriented syntax, do you know a fast way to decode all redirects inside notepad++ or another way to transform all ~ 150 redirects decoded in a single clicks? Will start looking a way now but please tell me if you know anything.

Comment: You could try just pasting your code/encoded URLs into an online [URL decoder/encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) and hitting the "decode" button - just be careful if there is anything that shouldn't be "decoded".

Comment: Yes, I knew this way a few years ago and also thought something that "doesn't need" to change will be changed --- But, gladly, only the codded aliases was decoded and it worked like a charm and now the 301s are working fine. Thank you!

Comment: I used this particular tool: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/